# What do you call the clear adhesive film used to shield electronics?

Tags: components, remote-control

I am a newbie and am just trying to fix the remote control for my electric fireplace.

I am trying to replace a <s>peanut butter</s> **dome** button with a contact switch.

Between the cover and the PCB board there is a plastic sheet with adhesive on each side with holes cut out for buttons.

**This adhesive sheet is what I need to replace**/use to affix the contact button.

Can anyone point me to the product or at least tell me what it is called?

Below is an example of the type of remote.

[image]

Comment: What on earth is a peanut butter button?

Comment: A button from a peanut butter keyboard, that is a keyboard that is completely sealed and on which you press buttons by deforming the plastic, thus being impervious to spills, such as peanut butter.  e.g. the keyboard used at McDonald's.

Comment: @bnieland - >.< Lol. You're talking about a membrane keyboard/keypad.

Comment: Here's how they're made. Both the sort with a soft, squishy feel and the ones with a more obvious 'click'. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewUzWdOvb84 - Perhaps a dome switch would work for you.

Comment: @bnieland That's called a membrane keyboard. I have never heard anyone call it a peanut butter keyboard before.

Comment: @Hearth - me either. :D When I googled it with great curiosity, the very first search result was for a YouTube video called "Kidtech My First Keyboard from 1994: It's Peanut Butter-Proof!" - that moment was golden. :)

Comment: The part which makes and breaks contact under the plastic is called [dome switch](https://www.keyelco.com/category.cfm/keyelco/Key-Pad-Dome-Switches/id/1191).

Comment: Hey folks, glad to provide some amusement :) So, the question is what is the name of the transparent adhesive sheet through which holes are cut to allow the dome switch to make the connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely a double-sided tape, such as '3M™ Adhesive Transfer Tape 467MP', I think.